# Multiple MySQL queries in one PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a PHP file which can perform different MySQL queries according to the data which is sent via POST. If I add another case to the switch statement, which executes a MySQL query, I get a fatal error: call to a member function prepare() on null.
The connection.php includes $conn.

I don't really know, why this occurs, so I'd be glad if someone could help :)

```
require_once('connection.php');

function namecheck($conn, $username)
{
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($username));
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;

    if ($result !== false) {
        return True;
    } else {
        return False;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch ($action) {

        case 'namecheck': //works
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $result = namecheck($conn, $username);
            if ($result == True) {
                echo 'True';
            } elseif ($result == False) {
                echo 'False';
            }

        case 'adduser': //script still works
            $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            try {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute(array($username, $password));
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                return $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }
            $conn = null;

        case 'test': //Same as above. if added, fatal error
            $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            try {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute(array($username, $password));
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                return $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }
            $conn = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *If I add another case to the switch statement, which executes a MySQL query, I get a fatal error: call to a member function prepare() on null.*

That's because you're executing `$conn = null;` statement in each of your cases and primarily because there's no `break;` statement in your switch-case. Without any `break;` statement, all the downstream cases(from the point where there's a match) will get executed. So your code block should be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action){
        case 'namecheck': 
            ...
            break;
        case 'adduser': 
            ...
            break;
        case 'test':
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have `break` statement in your case blocks. When "adduser" case is executed, control goes to "test" and `$conn` is null there

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-switch-case-statements.php

Replace `case 'test':` with following:

```
break;
case 'test':
```